# JavaScript to read indexed-PNG data

Tags: javascript, image

I love indexed-PNG. Using it, I've been able to define a "world map" for a 72x67 tile world (a total of 4,824 tiles) in just a single 571 byte image.

Now I want to use JavaScript to read this image's data.

I could very easily create a canvas, draw the image there, and then pull from its data. However, this will give me full RGB colour values.

The image right now uses the indexed palette with 0 being a wall, 1 being a path, 2 being a merchant, etc.. While distinct colours are used to make the image visually usable, is there any way for JavaScript to read the index of a colour at a particular pixel, akin to the `imagecolorat` function in PHP?

**Sample image**

[image]
<sub>(source: [adamhaskell.net](http://adamhaskell.net/img/map.png))</sub>

Comment: Do you have an example indexed PNG handy for us to test with?

Comment: yes; you simply take 4  rgba sub-pixels at once from the canvas imagedata to the get the rgba color of a given pixel. you do need to handle the rows and columns, but those are just multiplying factors for the r/c to reach pixel index.

Comment: @dandavis: But that’s the RGBA colour, which wouldn’t be visually distinct at values of (0, 0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 0.004, 1), (0, 0, 0.008, 1), etc..

Comment: there is no such thing as (0, 0, 0.008, 1) in canvas image data, they are all integers from 0-255, so combining them is precise and simple.

Comment: @dandavis: (0, 0, 0, 255), (0, 0, 1, 255), (0, 0, 2, 255) if you like.

Comment: if you want the same big number as php, just reverse the bitshifting found on the imagecolorat php documentation. numbers are numbers, and both formats can be losslessly converted back and forth.

Comment: @dandavis I am referring to indexed images, such as those given by PHP's `imagecreate` - NOT `imagecreatetruecolor`

Comment: You could try modifying [this part of PNG.js](https://github.com/devongovett/png.js/blob/master/png.js#L300).

Comment: you can rip a "step wedege" of all colors from a looped php incrementing output using canvas to see what it calls each color that php outputs to build a conversion table for JS>phpindex. there should only be 255 colors if my understanding is correct, and then you can easily concat rgba and use it as a key to reach the indexed value on the js side.

Answer (score 0):

You probably won't find a more convenient way of reading image data without passing it through an HTML5 Canvas first.

Not to say that there aren't alternatives!

Exhibit A: [pnglib.js](http://www.xarg.org/download/pnglib.js) (by [Robert Eisele](http://www.xarg.org/2010/03/generate-client-side-png-files-using-javascript/))

Exhibit B [png.js](https://github.com/devongovett/png.js/blob/master/png.js) (by [Devon Govett](https://github.com/devongovett)), though that's assuming you're using Node. His examples still use a canvas on the client side.

Comment: From Exhibit A: "// constructor takes height, ***weight*** and color-depth" I lol'd

Comment: I’m pretty sure pnglib.js is for *writing* PNGs.